# Can a Kafka consumer(0.8.2.2) read messages in batch

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

As per my understanding Kafka consumer reads messages from an assigned partition sequentially...

We are planning to have multiple Kafka consumer (Java) which has same group I'd ..so if it reads sequentially from an assigned partition then how we can achieve high throughput ..i.e. For Example Producer publishes messages like 40 per sec ...
Consumer process msg 1 per sec ..though we can have multiple consumers but cannot have 40 rt??? Correct me if I'm wrong...

And in our case consumer have to commit offset only after message is processed successfully ..else message will be reprocessed... Is there any better solution???

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous, your title seems to suggest you're asking whether a Kafka Consumer can read in batch, but your actual question talks more about how to balance certain processing requirements in Kafka. Are you wanting to know if Consumers can batch messages? Or are you asking how to get around your Producer (40 per sec) and Consumer (1 per sec) time/processing requirements?

Comment: i guess my question is related to the title...ill try to explain why...if single kafka consumer read messages in batch i can achieve similar throughput as producer.....so in my question i was asking that how to achieve high throughput with each consumer ...that can happen only if each consumer reads messages in batches...but as per my understanding kafka consumer reads messages sequentially from a partition...

Answer (score 21):

Based on your question clarification.

A Kafka Consumer can read multiple messages at a time. But a Kafka Consumer doesn't really read messages, its more correct to say a Consumer reads a certain number of bytes and then based on the size of the individual messages, that determines how many messages will be read. Reading through the [Kafka Consumer Configs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#consumerconfigs), you're not allowed to specify how many messages to fetch, you specify a max/min data size that a consumer can fetch. However many messages fit inside that range is how many you will get. You will always get messages sequentially as you have pointed out.

**Related Consumer Configs (for 0.9.0.0 and greater)**

- fetch.min.bytes
- max.partition.fetch.bytes

**UPDATE**

Using your example in the comments, "my understanding is if i specify in config to read 10 bytes and if each message is 2 bytes the consumer reads 5 messages at a time." That is true. Your next statement, "that means the offsets of these 5 messages were random with in partition" that is false. Reading sequential doesn't mean one by one, it just means that they remain ordered. You are able to batch items and have them remain sequential/ordered. Take the following examples.

In a Kafka log, if there are 10 messages (each 2 bytes) with the following offsets, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].

If you read 10 bytes, you'll get a batch containing the messages at offsets [0,1,2,3,4].

If you read 6 bytes, you'll get a batch containing the messages at offsets [0,1,2].

If you read 6 bytes, then another 6 bytes, you'll get two batches containing the messages [0,1,2] and [3,4,5].

If you read 8 bytes, then 4 bytes, you'll get two batches containing the messages [0,1,2,3] and [4,5].

**Update: Clarifying Committing**

I'm not 100% sure how committing works, I've mainly worked with Kafka from a Storm environment. The provided KafkaSpout automatically commits Kafka messages.

But looking through the [0.9.0.1 Consumer APIs](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html), which I would recommend you do to. There seems to be three methods in particular that are relevant to this discussion.

- poll(long timeout)
- commitSync()
- commitSync(java.util.Map offsets)

The poll method retrieves messages, could be only 1, could be 20, for your example lets say 3 messages were returned [0,1,2]. You now have those three messages. Now it's up you to determine how to process them. You could process them 0 => 1 => 2, 1 => 0 => 2, 2 => 0 => 1, it just depends. However you process them, after processing you'll want to commit which tells the Kafka server you're done with those messages.

Using the commitSync() commits everything returned on last poll, in this case it would commit offsets [0,1,2].

On the other hand, if you choose to use commitSync(java.util.Map offsets), you can manually specify which offsets to commit. If you're processing them in order, you can process offset 0 then commit it, process offset 1 then commit it, finally process offset 2 and commit.

All in all, Kafka gives you the freedom to process messages how to desire, you can choose to process them sequentially or entirely random at your choosing.

Comment: this is were im confused when you say "A Kafka Consumer can read multiple messages at a time"  my understanding is if i specify in config to read 10 bytes and if each message is 2 bytes the consumer reads 5 messages at a time...that means the offsets of these 5 messages were random with in partition...??? and you also said "You will always get messages sequentially as you have pointed out"  this means eventhough consumer will be able to get 5 messages but each message comes to consumer(consumer will be able to read)  one by one ? then the first statement is contradictory.correct me if im wrong

Comment: Updated answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Sorry for delay ...ok I got that now let us take 3rd example I read  6 bytes i.e. 3 messages with offsets [0,1,2] ..I receive this messages as an array .. And it's upto consumer to process them sequentially or parallely... In any case how to commit offset (either manual or auto) I mean take 1st message I read from offset  0 once I process it to which number I have to commit offset...so that it's not processed again????

Comment: Updated answer again.

Comment: So i can process all the batch messages which consumer read at a time I mean parallely and call commitSync() so that all the messages will be committed parallely???

Comment: That's what the APIs say, though I've never used them myself. Make sure you're using the 0.9.x.x apis though.

Comment: You mean only this version of APIs only have these 3 methods..I guess even old version has manual commit

Comment: Yes, the consumer was changed in 0.9.0.0 version, so before that its different.

Comment: If there are 3 messages, each 3 bytes, you'll consume 3 messages. If there's one 3 bytes message and one 8 bytes message, you'll consume just the first message, because 3 + 8 = 11 doesn't fit into 10.

Comment: @morganw09dev all the above features(reading batch,commiting offsets to kafka) cannot be achieved if i use consumer version 0.8.2.2??? im really concerened ..please clarify..

Comment: That's correct, Kafka rewrote its consumer for 0.9.x, so my answer only applies to 0.9.x consumers.

Comment: @morganw09dev 1) im able to see  "fetch.min.bytes" ...in http://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html#consumerconfigs but not "max.partition.fetch.bytes"  and in my case i can set only fetch.min.bytes =10 ,so that at a time consumer reads 5 messages (size 2 bytes)... ??   2) you mean i cannot manual commit offsets in 0.8.2.2 consumer version???  3)And which api(simple or highlevel consumer) i have to use to fulfill my purpose in version 0.8.2.2 ?? cos to use 0.9 consumer we have to upgrade our enterprise brokers which might not happen in the near future..please suggest!!

Comment: I think you're going to have to figure this one out by yourself. Look through the api yourself see what the offer you and how you can use them. You are handicapping yourself by expecting me or anyone else to solve all our programming issues.

Comment: v0.8 works exactly as @morganw09dev described, regarding `fetch.min.bytes`.

Comment: "my understanding is if i specify in config to read 10 bytes and if each message is 2 bytes the consumer reads 5 messages at a time."  how can I do this dynamically if the size of my messages is different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve parallelism, which seems to be what you're asking, you use topic partitions (you split topic on N parts which are called partitions).
Then, in the consumer, you spawn multiple threads to consume from those partitions.

On the Producer side, you publish messages to random partition (default) or you provide Kafka with some message attribute to calculate hash (if ordering is required), which makes sure that all msgs with the same hash go to the same partition.

**EDIT (example of offset commit request):**
This is how I did it. All methods that are not provided are non-essential.

```
 /**
   * Commits the provided offset for the current client (i.e. unique topic/partition/clientName combination)
   * 
   * @param offset
   * @return {@code true} or {@code false}, depending on whether commit succeeded
   * @throws Exception
   */
  public static boolean commitOffset(String topic, int partition, String clientName, SimpleConsumer consumer,
      long offset) throws Exception {
    try {
      TopicAndPartition tap = new TopicAndPartition(topic, partition);
      OffsetAndMetadata offsetMetaAndErr = new OffsetAndMetadata(offset, OffsetAndMetadata.NoMetadata(), -1L);
      Map<TopicAndPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> mapForCommitOffset = new HashMap<>(1);
      mapForCommitOffset.put(tap, offsetMetaAndErr);

      kafka.javaapi.OffsetCommitRequest offsetCommitReq = new kafka.javaapi.OffsetCommitRequest(
          ConsumerContext.getMainIndexingConsumerGroupId(), mapForCommitOffset, 1, clientName,
          ConsumerContext.getOffsetStorageType());

      OffsetCommitResponse offsetCommitResp = consumer.commitOffsets(offsetCommitReq);
      Short errCode = (Short) offsetCommitResp.errors().get(tap);
      if (errCode != 0) {
        processKafkaOffsetCommitError(tap, offsetCommitResp, BrokerInfo.of(consumer.host()));
        ErrorMapping.maybeThrowException(errCode);
      }
      LOG.debug("Successfully committed offset [{}].", offset);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error("Error while committing offset [" + offset + "].", e);
      throw e;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Ok for the producer part...what is the advantage I'll get if I specify messages to be placed in specific partition over default partition..anyway as a consumer I'll just pass the topic name...

Comment: And other question 1) in which format the message is stored in partition ..all I know is producer sends message in Json format to Kafka

Comment: First question: that's used when you need to assure that messages will get consumed in the same order as they were received/produced. Let's say you have e.g. `PersonTransaction` messages, you'd hash them by `personId` so that transactions of the same person always go to the same partition.

Comment: Second question: messages are stored in binary format on brokers.

Comment: For first question example which you gave I have similar requirement... Can I mention list of operations(for example 3)to be performed in a single message so that if 3rd operation is failed I'll revert the first 2 operations and I'll not commit the message so that it will be retried ...

Comment: No we have 0.8.2.2 ,can't I use low/high level consumer??? Do we really need to migrate to 0.9 cos that needs brokers upgrade as well

Comment: you mean i cannot commit offset to kafka if i use 0.8.2.2 version of consumers???thats really surprising

Comment: You don't need to migrate, you have low level consumer in 0.8 where you have complete control over when to commit offsets. So you'll simply make sure that you first do everything you need to do with a message and only then commit offset.

Comment: Ok but in 0.9 consumer Api there is already a method "commitSync" ..which is not present in older versions ..how to manual commit in 0.8.2.X consumer APIs ??please lemme know if there is any sample

Comment: I edited my answer to include example of offset commit. Please close this question.

Comment: While producing I'm inserting into default partition ..how will my consumer will know to which partition it has to commit  in the above code which you have provided  ??And wat is client name here ..name of the consumer??

Comment: We will have all consumers tied to a single group I'd

Comment: There's no groups here, this is low-level consumer. I think you need to write some code and post the parts of code when you get stuck (in a new question, where you'll post a link to this question).

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the messages in batches and process them in a batched manner. 
batch.max.wait.ms (property)
the consumer will wait this amount of time and polls for new message

Comment: Could you please clarify, do you mean `fetch.max.wait.ms`? There is apparently no  `batch.max.wait.ms` property.