# How can I make a batch consumer with kafka-python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've been looking for a while but I can't find a way to create a `batch consumer` with [kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python). I found a guide for [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623057/can-a-kafka-consumer0-8-2-2-read-messages-in-batch) but it isn't exactly what I am trying to achieve. Indeed, my goal is just to consume a fixed number of records let's say and process them (perform some transformations) and after that, store them into a Database.

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/252 is the closest thing I can see, under work though.

Answer (score 1):

this is one consumer argument:

> max_poll_records (int) – The maximum number of records returned in a
>   single call to poll(). Default: 500

i think kafka-python can do batch consume with a max number of records, maybe not exactly what your saying a fixed number.

Comment: Another question, in the examples I've seen they iterate over each message independently, how does this change with this option?

Comment: i think it's same as only one. consumer may pull max_poll_records in one poll request, and process one by one