# Poll several messages from Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, confluent-platform

I'm using [confluent_kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) package for working with Kafka.
I create topic in this way:

```
from confluent_kafka import avro
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroProducer

def my_producer():
    bootstrap_servers=['my_adress.com:9092',
                    'my_adress.com:9092']

    value_schema = avro.load('/home/ValueSchema.avsc')

    avroProducer = AvroProducer({
        'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers[0]+','+bootstrap_servers[1],
        'schema.registry.url':'http://my_adress.com:8081',
        },
        default_value_schema=value_schema
        )

    for i in range(0, 25000):
        value = {"name":"Yuva","favorite_number":10,"favorite_color":"green","age":i*2}
        avroProducer.produce(topic='my_topik14', value=value)
        avroProducer.flush(0)
    print('Finished!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_producer()
```

It works. (this get 24820 messages instead of 25000 by the way...)
We can check it:

```
kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list my_adress.com:9092 --topic my_topik14
my_topik14:0:24819
```

Now I want to consume:

```
from confluent_kafka import KafkaError
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroConsumer
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer import SerializerError

bootstrap_servers=['my_adress.com:9092',
                   'my_adress.com:9092']
c = AvroConsumer(
    {'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers[0]+','+bootstrap_servers[1],
     'group.id': 'avroneversleeps',
     'schema.registry.url': 'http://my_adress.com:8081',
     'api.version.request': True,
     'fetch.min.bytes': 100000,
     'consume.callback.max.messages':1000,
     'batch.num.messages':2
     })
c.subscribe(['my_topik14'])
running = True

while running:
    msg = None
    try:
        msg = c.poll(0.1)
        if msg:
            if not msg.error():
                print(msg.value())
                c.commit(msg)
            elif msg.error().code() != KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
                print(msg.error())
                running = False
        else:
            print("No Message!! Happily trying again!!")
    except SerializerError as e:
        print("Message deserialization failed for %s: %s" % (msg, e))
        running = False
c.commit()
c.close()
```

But there is a problem:
I read messages just one by one.
**My question is How to read batch of messages?**
I tried different parameters in Consumer config but they didn't cnahge anything!

---

Also I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623057/can-a-kafka-consumer0-8-2-2-read-messages-in-batch) on SO and tried the same parameters - it still doesn't work.

Also read this. But this is against the previous link...

Comment: Can you try this instead to count the number of messages from the beginning `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server my_adress.com:9092  --topic my_topik14 --from-beginning | wc ` and see if that returns 25K messages?

Comment: @St1id3r thank you for responce. I can't figure out how to modify your command to make it work! If I just copy it I get  `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh: No such file or directory`. If I add parameter `--from-beginning` to my command, I get ` from-beginning is not a recognized option`

Comment: That is strange, you should be having that utility in bin. Link to documentation: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_consume

Comment: can you try just with `kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server my_adress.com:9092 --topic my_topik14 --from-beginning | wc` . Looks like you have those utilities on your path from above command `kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list my_adress.com:9092 --topic my_topik14
my_topik14:0:24819`

Comment: My bad, omit the .sh as well in the above command.

Comment: I tried this `kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server my_adress.com:9092 --topic my_topik14 --from-beginning | wc` . It freezes process, but if I press Ctrl+C I see message `Processed a total of 24819 messages`.

Maybe the problem in some config property? For example, because of some parameter, it rounds the number of records to a round number in bytes (10,000 ...) ?

Comment: Ah, I see. It is not freeze, the console consumer will be continuosly polling the server for new messages and prints as it sees it. So, its just waiting for new messages and you dont need `| wc` part in the command as its already printing you the number of processed messages. Also, about rounding, I dont think it is doing anything as such. 1. I have also spotted that you are using `avroProducer.flush(0)`, what is your intention behind it? 2. Can you try without it and see? 3. Did consume() answer your question of polling a batch of messages? 4. If so, can you please mark it as answer ? :)

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam
what version of python and confluent_kafka are you using? Trying to repro this consumer without hardcoding a schema, which most other tutorials require (see https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/5.5.0-post/clients/cloud/python). Getting different errors depending on which versions I specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AvroConsumer have no `consume` method. But it is easy to make my own implementation of this method as there is in Consume class (parent of AvroConsumer).
Here is the code:

```
def consume_batch(self, num_messages=1, timeout=None):
    """
    This is an overriden method from confluent_kafka.Consumer class. This handles batch of message
    deserialization using avro schema

    :param int num_messages: number of messages to read in one batch (default=1)
    :param float timeout: Poll timeout in seconds (default: indefinite)
    :returns: list of messages objects with deserialized key and value as dict objects
    :rtype: Message
    """
    messages_out = []
    if timeout is None:
        timeout = -1
    messages = super(AvroConsumer, self).consume(num_messages=num_messages, timeout=timeout)
    if messages is None:
        return None
    else:
        for m in messages:
            if not m.value() and not m.key():
                return messages
            if not m.error():
                if m.value() is not None:
                    decoded_value = self._serializer.decode_message(m.value())
                    m.set_value(decoded_value)
                if m.key() is not None:
                    decoded_key = self._serializer.decode_message(m.key())
                    m.set_key(decoded_key)
                messages_out.append(m)
    #print(len(message))
    return messages_out
```

But after that we run test and this method give no any performance increasing. So looks like it just for better usability. Or I need to make some additional work about serializing not single message, but whole batch.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using  `consume([num_messages=1][, timeout=-1])` method. API ref. here:

For Consumer:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.consume

For AvroConsumer:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html?highlight=avroconsumer#confluent_kafka.Consumer.consume

More about the issue here:

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/252

Comment: Thank you for responce. You get a little mistake in your question: there is no `consume` method for AvroConsumer - second link adresses to the same place as first.

Comment: But the code in the github issue made me think about consume implementation for AvroConsumer class. I'll show it here.

Comment: Please, see my answer too!