# Two consumers in the same consumer group, only one actually consumes, other one is idle

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two instances of the same service reading from a topic. 
Topic has 4 partitions. 
Consumer group id is the same, however only one instance actually processes messages - the other one stays idle after successfully subscribing to the topic, according to the logs. 
My understanding was I can speed up the processing by adding more consumers. 
How do I run several consumers in parallel? What did I miss?

Comment: How many messages did you produce? Consumers fetch messages in batch, so maybe they all were fetched at once. I simplified it. Here you can read more in depth version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35630897/5058677

Comment: producer writes by one message, consumer handles in one hour far more than batch size configured on consumer side

Comment: One more thing, are all messages spread throught partitions? Or maybe they were written to one

Comment: I'll have to check that

Comment: Out of curiosity, was that the issue?

Comment: @Rumid I haven't checked it yet, but according to the producer it should be balancing based on message key